# NullPointerException в условии if

Tags: java, исключения, if

В классе 3 метода: save, get и delete

```
public class Storage {
Somedata[] storage = new Somedata[5];
int i = 0;

void save(Somedata r) {
    i++;
    storage[i - 1] = r;
}

Somedata get(String uuid) {
    int j;
    for (j=0; j < storage.length; j++) {
        if (storage[j].uuid == uuid) {
            return storage[j];
        } else return null;
    }
    return storage[j];
}

void delete(String uuid) {
    for (int m=0; m < storage.length; m++) {
        if (storage[m].uuid == uuid) {
            storage[m]=null;
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

Соответственно, создают, достают и удаляют объекты класса Somedata из массива storage;
Метод, из которого должны вызываться методы

```
 public class MainArray {    
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 private final static Storage STORAGE = new Storage();
        String uuid = null;
   // Подробности ввода uuid через System.in опущены //

            case "save":
                r = new Somedata();
                r.uuid = uuid;
                STORAGE.save(r);
                break;
            case "get":
                System.out.println(STORAGE.get(uuid));
                break;
            case "delete":
                STORAGE.delete(uuid);
                break;             
   }    
  }
```

Для условия if (storage[m].uuid == uuid) метода delete выдает ошибку  NullPointerException

Но метод get работает без ошибки. В нем реализовано такое же условие if (storage[m].uuid == uuid)     И на него NullPointerException не выскакивает...

Comment: Пардон, а какой у вас вопрос?

Comment: Почему возникает NullPointerException Для условия if (storage[m].uuid == uuid) метода delete?

Comment: А вы смотрели что находится в массиве на момент удаления?

Comment: Все, понял! Я не учел, что цикл в delete надо, вообще говоря, прервать. Он же будет по всем элементам массива пробегаться. И рано или поздно "наткнется" на null. Там он и получит в лоб NullPointerExceptionю

Answer (score 1):

ты возвращаешь первый элемент если он подходит, или `null` если не подходит

```
Somedata get(String uuid) {
    int j;
    for (j=0; j < storage.length; j++) {
        if (storage[j].uuid == uuid) {
            return storage[j];
        } 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Ошибка была в методе delete. Но за get тоже спасибо - так будет более корректно - поправил

Comment: @Andrey1981spb поставь плюсики если считаешь ответы полезными

Comment: плюсанул. Хотя мои плюсы пока не отображаются

Comment: @Andrey1981spb ахах! я тот еще хитрец. +18 баллов для тебя :P

Comment: :-) хакнуть обстоятельства

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку. Надо было прервать цикл, чтобы он не дошел до null-элементов. Реализовал это через break;

```
  void delete(String uuid) {
    int m;
    for (m=0; m < storage.length; m++) {
     if (storage[m] != null) {
        if (storage[m].uuid == uuid) {
            storage[m]=null;
            break;
           }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

да, но ты забыл про пустые места в своем хранилище!

```
void delete(String uuid) {
  int m;
  for (m=0; m < storage.length; m++) {
      if (storage[m]!=null && storage[m].uuid == uuid) {
          storage[m]=null;
          return;
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: точно! спасибо, добрый человек!